# Загрузка Ajax элементов в Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Здравсвуйте, 
использую Selenium (Java). Проект активно использует Ajax. 
Проблема в том, что во многих местах приходится стаить команду Thread.sleep (4000) чтобы все элементы могли загрузиться на страницу. Искал в интернете пример кода чтобы все элементы Ajax загрузились на страницу и только потом выполнять дальнейшие действия. Не могу понять как это работает. Я новичок в Java поэтому сложновато. Аытался использовать вот этот код: `public boolean waitForAjax() {

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);

ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jQueryLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
  @Override
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    try {
      return ((Long)((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return jQuery.active") == 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

      return true;
    }
  }
};


ExpectedCondition<Boolean> jsLoad = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
  @Override
  public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
    return ((JavascriptExecutor)getDriver()).executeScript("return document.readyState")
    .toString().equals("complete");
  }
};
```

return wait.until(jQueryLoad) && wait.until(jsLoad);
}`

но ничего не получилось.

Сегодня сделал обходной вариант типа ExpectedConditions, и использую опции InvisibilityOfElementLocated, ElementToBeClickable. Но работает через раз. Хотелось бы пприменить код чтобы ждал полную загрузку Ajax элементов и только после этого выполнялись все действия.

Если кто знает, помогите с кодом. Спасибо!

Comment: В селениум нет возможности ожидать окончание асинхронного запроса. На то они и асинхронные - могут вообще никогда ничего не вернуть, и пользователь об этом не узнает (если явно не указано другое в коде приложения). Единственно нормальное решение - использовать явные ожидания. Если у вас они работают через раз, то вы делаете их неправльно

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [документации](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) есть 2 способа ожидания:
1. явный (по событиям, условиям)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

Список условий можно найти [тут](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions)
2. неявный (ожидания выполнения всех скриптов и загрузок)

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading");
WebElement myDynamicElement = 
driver.findElement(By.id("myDynamicElement"));
```

Comment: Я знаком с перечисленными вариантами, попробовал их перед тем как задать вопрос, но не сработало. Нужно сделать так, чтобы сначала шла проверка на завершение обработки на странице JavaScript и jQuery. Но как это прописать в коде не знаю.