# Java selenium не открывается страница google drive

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Java selenium не открывается страница google drive

Сама страница https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11j7w_MkBJyxY66Rt1-N8yWIbj7KXD6Bd

Если открыть в обычном браузере, то файлы отображаются нормально http://prntscr.com/mncvfq

Когда эту же страницу открываю при помощи  selenium.WebDriver , то файлы не отображаются http://prntscr.com/mncwj1

Почему? Как сделать, чтоб отображались?

Вот мой код:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.pathGoogleDriver);
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

        try {
            driver.get("https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11j7w_MkBJyxY66Rt1-N8yWIbj7KXD6Bd");
            Thread.sleep(30000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую воспользоватся возможностями класса WebDriverWait, также [вот](https://xpinjection.com/articles/waits-and-timeouts-in-webdriver/) не плохая статья.
Пример утилитного класса:

```
public final class WebDriverUtils {
    private WebDriverUtils() {
    }

    public static void waitFor(WebDriver driver, By waitingElementLocator, int secToWait) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, secToWait);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(waitingElementLocator));
    }

    public static void waitForNot(WebDriver driver, By waitingElementLocator, int secToWait) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, secToWait);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(waitingElementLocator)));
    }
}
```

Comment: по теме нашел [тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788059/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-ajax-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-selenium-java?rq=1)

Comment: WebDriverWait это конечно хорошо, но проблему это не решает...

Comment: Абсолютно решает. Признак дурного тона использовать Thread.sleep. 
И так же признак дурного тона использовать скачанный драйвер, вместо того чтоб подгружать последнюю версию, это, кстати, и есть ваша проблема, вероятнее всего. Советую изучить библиотеку [webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager), и прикрутить  WebDriverWait или [Awaitility](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility) (это более интересный вариант).