# Как проверить, что элемент отсутствует на странице?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation, testng

Проверка состоит в том, что при правильном заполнении регистрационной формы, элемент, выдающий ошибку (при неправильном заполнении) отсутствует и никаких ошибок нет. Как это реализовать правильнее, с точки зрения тестирования?

Comment: может быть надо сначала убедиться 1) что данные введены правильно и юзер все ввел (наверняка есть какой-то элемент на форме который это подтверждает) -  а затем 2) проверить наличие или видимость элементов, сообщающих об ошибке. Или какая-то проблема с этим?

Answer (score 1):

Советую воспользоватся возможностями класса `WebDriverWait`, также [вот](https://xpinjection.com/articles/waits-and-timeouts-in-webdriver/) и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/788059/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-ajax-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-selenium-java?rq=1) не плохой материал для изучения. Пример утилитного класса:

```
public final class WebDriverUtils {
    private WebDriverUtils() {
    }

    public static void waitFor(WebDriver driver, By waitingElementLocator, int secToWait) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, secToWait);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(waitingElementLocator));
    }

    public static void waitForNot(WebDriver driver, By waitingElementLocator, int secToWait) {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, secToWait);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(waitingElementLocator)));
    }
}
```

2й метод как раз отвечает на поставленный вами вопрос.